# How to make an existing SVN branch read only to all users?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have an existing SVN branch.  I've created a new branch.

All developers are supposed to perform all future code check ins to the new branch.

To make sure there are no stragglers, I want to make the old branch 100% read only (for me as well).

How can I do that?

(Just FYI, I'm using Tortoise SVN 1.9.2 as a client.)

Answer (score 3):

- You can't do it on client-side with client-side tools
- If [path based authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html) enabled on server, you can  just add additional section with old branch into `AuthzSVNAccessFile` and block write access to all users
- If using path based authorization not possible for any reason, you have to use pre-commit hook with `svnlook dirs-changed` and some logic in it for rejecting commits into protected branch